# Why does beautifulsoup return an empty list (but not when run in interpreter?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, empty-list

I am writing a simple program to scrape flight data off of travel websites.

When I test this in the python interpreter, it works fine. However, when I run it as .py file, it returns an empty list.

I know that the program is able to get the data from the site, because I can print the entire source no problem. However, for some reason the `find_all` method is returning an empty list.

The part that should work:

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    raw_page_data = urllib2.urlopen(query_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page_data, 'html.parser')
    raw_prices = soup.find_all(class_='price-whole')

    for item in raw_prices:
        for character in item:
            if character.isdigit() == True:
                print character
```

Usually, in the interpreter, this returns a list of prices. I cannot print raw_prices at all, as it is empty. I believe that the error is with the `find_all` method, because the output is [].

I have been told that, perhaps, the JavaScript on the site is not loading the elements I am trying to find. However, this makes no sense since the entirety of the page source is loaded, and printable. If I try `print soup`, 
it prints the entire source (which contains the elements I am trying to find).

I tried with different parser as well, to check if there was a bug.

Any help greatly appreciated cheers!

Comment: Show us a complete example.  At a minimum, the code in your question is missing the imports.  Also show us the exact commands you're using to start the interpreter and execute your script.

Comment: I start the interpreter by typing python in terminal,
and i start the script by typing python followed by the path to the script in terminal

Comment: OK, so at least we know this isn't a python version mismatch issue.

Comment: Also of note, the website i am scraping is flighthub.com.
this website puts a loading screen first, so perhaps this is returning an empty list because beautifulsoup is grabbing the loading screen?
Perhaps this doesnt occur in the interpreter because script is executing more slowly? Is there perhaps a way to wait fot the page to completely finish loading without using import time, time.sleep(20) method because this doesnt work for me.

Comment: If the elements are present when you `print soup`, then I wouldn't think page loading delay is the issue.